# file for saving cookie data not found when using HTTP::Cookies in Perl script

Tags: perl, cookies

all. I had some questions about the Perl module HTTP::Cookies. The example on CPAN is like below:

```
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( file => '$ENV{\'HOME\'}/lwp_cookies.dat', autosave => 1);
```

The lwp_cookies.dat file is used to save cookie data on my local machine as I understand. On my machine, '$ENV{\'HOME\'}' is an empty path. The script runs good, even after execution I can't find any file named "lwp_cookies.dat" on my machine. I changed '$ENV{\'HOME\'}' to '$ENV{\'TMP\'}', which is a path really exists after I verified by Perl print. Still I can't find the "lwp_cookies.dat" in my TEMP folder. My first question is how the HTTP::Cookies is working with the "lwp_cookies.dat" file.

On the other hand, on one of my systems(all're Windows system as mentioned here), the same code produce error message below: 
Can't open $ENV{'HOME'}/lwp_cookies.dat: No such file or directory

So it's strange to me. On my good system, even file or path not exists, the script runs well, which I suppose the file is created on some temp memory instead; on bad system, the code example doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the $ENV{'HOME'} variable to interpolate into the string, you need double quotes; single quotes don't interpolate variables:

```
`file => "$ENV{'HOME'}/lwp_cookies.dat",`
```

Comment: Great. That's the key I forgot that.